# Return Item from List with Minimum Value

Tags: c#, list, min

I have a List of Items:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
items.add(new Item("cow", 4));
items.add(new Item("pig", 7));
items.add(new Item("dog", 12));
```

I want to retreive the item with the minimum `Value` (where the numbers are that `Value`).  How would I do that?

I am trying to avoid a nasty `foreach` loop.  I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
return items.Min(Value);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the minimum value first, then get the item that has the minimum value:

```
var minValue = items.Min(x => x.Value);
var item = items.First(x => x.Value == minValue);
```

You can also do that in one line that won't be efficient because it will perform `Min` for each item:

```
var item = items.First(x => x.Value == items.Min(x => x.Value));
```

Comment: Select is not an option for a List<Item>

Comment: @Evorlor why is that ?

Comment: It says List<> does not contain a definition for it

Comment: you need `using System.Linq;` add using directive to top of your code.

Comment: it's just that this would iterate your collection 2N times (worst case). The solution I suggested would iterate once (N time).

Comment: @mB. I also know how to do this using a loop.but the OP doesn't want to use a loop: _I am trying to avoid a nasty foreach loop._

Answer (score 2):

You can order the items by the `Value`, then use `First` to take the lowest:

```
Item lowestValueItem = items
    .OrderBy(i => i.Value)
    .First();
```

Another (more efficient) way, [`MinBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c) of [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

Comment: Thanks! I am looking for efficiency on this one. Do you know if this answer or selman's answer is more efficient?  or if the difference is insignificant?

Comment: @Evorlor: you can use MoreLinq's `MinBy`. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a utility method to do that which is quite efficient and re-usable!
It only iterates over collection once (n complexity).

```
public static TItem GetMinItem<TItem>(this IEnumerable<TItem> items) where TItem : IComparable<TItem>
{
    TItem minItem = default(TItem);
     bool isFirstItem = true;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (isFirstItem)
            {
                minItem = item;
                isFirstItem = false;
            }
        else
        {
            if (item.CompareTo(minItem) < 0)
            {
                minItem = item;
            }
        }
    }
    return minItem;
}
```

In order to be generic, the method needs TItem to be implementing IComparable. In your case, your Item class could implement like below:

```
public class Item : IComparable<Item>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Item other)
        {
            return this.Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
        }
    }
```